# How can I get all records of a field from a form?

Tags: zoho

I am trying to get all the records of a field from a form but I am getting only one record from a form.

I am using the below code

```
<%{

Alphabet_List = Alphabet[ID>0].Character;%>
<%=Alphabet_List%>

<%}%>
```

1. Alphabet is a form name
2. Character is a field name which contains A-Z.

when running this code I am getting only "A" but the output I am expecting is A-Z.

Please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

use the getall function. Also you can make ID != null

Here:

```
<%{(Alphabet_List = Alphabet[ID>0].Character).getall();%>
```